# How to share an object in multiple jvm?

Tags: java

I want to share an Object between an web application which is running in two different Java Virtual Machine. How can i achieve this?

Comment: as cached object? or multiples jvm can update object at the same time?

Comment: Why do you need that? Can you please explain the need?

Comment: Sorry I should have explained more, this application is deployed in multiple Vm's, So my problem is I need to share or maintain say a session object through out my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't share an object, because memory addresses are different for two JVM.

You can share a copy of the same object on two jvm, but any change to that object on the first JVM is not reflected to the second jvm.

So if you need to share informations between two JVM you can do that in many different ways:

- Save data to a shared database
- Save data to a shared file
- Save data to an external web service that offer methods to save and read data
- Save data to an external cache system like REDIS